# Drupal delete token by calling push_notification service from android

Tags: android, rest, drupal, drupal-7

I have tried to register my device by calling the push notification service which stores tokens inside `push_notification_token` table.

Registering the token is no problem but in the same app i wanted to delete the token from the table in some situation so i was trying to see if same service is helpful or not.

I tried calling the service by using URL `http://mysite/endpoint/push_notifications` to register the token where i will pass parameters as `token` is token generated from GCM service and `type` is android. This is working fine.

So to delete the token what is the procedure.

Comment: hi can you please share your registration Post Request code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by following these steps.

1) Used DELETE method instead of normal POST method

2) Sent the tokens in the URL => http://example.com/endpoint_name/push_notifications/{token}

Like http://example.com/endpoint_name/push_notifications/abcgr123 whole token value in the end.

This will delete that token from the database.